# How do you change name of the internal storage memory in an Android device

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I am using Android 4.4.4 on a device called GPD XD.

Right now, I see that when I connect the device to the computer via USB, both the internal memory and the external memory card are called "SD Card". This is causing some issues to the OS, since it can't see the folders on the SD card, due the fact that both internal and external memory has the same name.

How do you change the name of the internal device? I did search but found nothing relevant. I believe some app that I downloaded (emulators from the google play store), did change the name, because last time that I did use the device, it was working fine and the name of the internal storage was not "SD Card" for sure.